# draw line under TextView on Android

Tags: android, textview, line

I have a layout that adds textviews dynamically and I want to divide each textview with a line.

Something like that:

```
TextView
 -----------------
TextView
 -----------------
TextView
 -----------------
```

I have found ways to underline the text, but I want to draw a line with a fixed size not underline the text.

Comment: Make an ImageView and show a line in it. Add the ImageView after every TextView.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

This is the simplest and most similar to using the `<hr>` tag in HTML:

Put this in your XML layout where you want the line:

```
<View 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="1dp"       
   android:background="#ffffff" />
```

This will draw a white line, 1 dp thick, across the screen. If you want it to be a fixed width, just change the `layout_width` to the dp size you want. Change the `background` to the HTML color code of your choice.

Comment: Is there a way to reuse this without having to put this XML layout everytime? Like for example we have shapes which are in the drawables and I can reuse it.

Comment: If i have 100 lines then I need to add 100 textviews and views for lines?

Comment: how to make it programmatically

Answer (score 18):

just add this **style**:

```
style="?android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
```

to your **TextView**

Comment: This messes up all of your other styles like textsize so not a good solution.

Comment: @John61590 How come?

Answer (score 7):

If you want to add programmatically then do this:

```
mTextView.setPaintFlags(mTextView.getPaintFlags()| Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
```

or you can add this to strings.xml:

```
<string name="your_string_here"><u>This is an underline</u>.</string>
```

or :

```
SpannableString spannableStringObject= new SpannableString("Your text here");
spannableStringObject.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, 
spannableStringObject.length(), 0);
textView.setText(spannableStringObject);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can build a ListView, it has a divider, and you can add line dynamically。