# How to inhrit style="?android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle" style and change the line color to blue?

Tags: android, styles, textview

I want to have a line below a text view with a blue color I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9370746/draw-line-under-textview-on-android) in this post  having this as a one of the answer I tried it and is working fine but I want to change the color of the textview and the line below it.

just add this style:

```
style="?android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
```

to your TextView

I also have tried extracting the style but it is giving me error while inheriting the said style

My style is as follows

```
<style name="blueBoldText" parent="?android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/DarkTurquoise</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Did you reach a solution ?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the value of the attribute

> ?android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle

is

```
@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.TextView.ListSeparator
```

So you can inherit this style instead.

Comment: Please explain how did you found out the relation between these two? Where can I check it? Thank you!

UPDATE: Now I see, here:
https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/themes.xml

Comment: I just use the function "search for declaration" (F3 sur Eclipse and Ctrl-B sur Android Studio). Il will open the declaration.
Or if you search for text in the source folder of the platform, you will find this line of code:

<item name="listSeparatorTextViewStyle">@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.TextView.ListSeparator</item>

Comment: Is this not public anymore? Although the editor seems to accept the value, the compiler generates: `Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.TextView.ListSeparator'.`

Answer (score 1):

You can extend TextView and set listSeparatorTextViewStyle.

```
public class HeaderView extends TextView {
    public HeaderView(Context context) {
        super(context, null, android.R.attr.listSeparatorTextViewStyle);
    }
    public HeaderView(Context context,
                    AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs, android.R.attr.listSeparatorTextViewStyle);
    }
}
```

then

```
<com.gmail.sikambr.alib.HeaderView
    style="@style/your_style"
    android:text="..."
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```