# Programmatically draw line under TextView

Tags: android, textview

I have a layout that adds `TextView`'s in loop dynamically:

```
TextView msg = new TextView(this);
TextView Bmsg = new TextView(this);
msg.setText(splittedItem[0]);
msg.setTextColor(0xFF2C85A6);
msg.setTextSize(22);
msg.setPadding(10, 10, 0, 10);
Bmsg.setText("- "+splittedItem[1]);
Bmsg.setPadding(20, 0, 10, 30);
Bmsg.setTextSize(18);
linearLayout.addView(msg);
linearLayout.addView(Bmsg);
```

And I want to divide each `TextView` with a line like this:

[image]

I need a line under `Bmsg`. I have found this - [draw line under TextView on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9370746/draw-line-under-textview-on-android), but I do not understand how to make this programmatically.

in XML:

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/buttonlayout">
 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this and let me know if it works

```
View view = new View(this);
view.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,2
));
view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));

linearlayout.addView(view);
```

Comment: Yet you should take pixel density into consideration instead of using `2` as this may not always give the same results.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to your styles list:

```
   <style name="DividerHorizontal">
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">1dp</item>
        <item name="android:background">?android:attr/listDivider</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DividerVertical">
        <item name="android:layout_width">1dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:background">?android:attr/listDivider</item>
    </style>
```

Once you do that, you can call it with a View like this:

```
   <View style="@style/DividerHorizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:id="@+id/topDivider" />
```

**EDIT:**

Since you seem to want to make a list, just use a ListView and do something similar or use this in the code:

```
    mListView = getListView();
    mAdapter = new ServersListAdapter(this, new String[] {},
            new String[] {}, new String[] {});
    int[] colors = { Color.parseColor("#D3D3D3"), Color.parseColor("#D3D3D3"), Color.parseColor("#D3D3D3") };
    mListView.setDivider(new GradientDrawable(Orientation.RIGHT_LEFT, colors));
```

Comment: 've got everything working, so your variant I do not understand how to use in my code

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) to display your TextViews, this could give you better flexibility and depending on what you do, better performance too.

You can use [RecyclerView.ItemDecoration](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ItemDecoration.html) to make dividers (and other things).